ASP.NET Core 8 Web API : no service for type ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter has been registered
I have a fresh ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project setup, but I am running into an issue when attempting to implement AntiForgery tokens.
Specifically, I'm having an issue when I protect an action on my controller with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken].
I get no build errors and the action returns data when I don't use the attribute. But with the attribute added I get an exception

System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter' has been registered.
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.DefaultFilterProvider.ProvideFilter(FilterProviderContext context, FilterItem filterItem)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.DefaultFilterProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(FilterProviderContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.FilterFactory.CreateUncachedFiltersCore(IFilterProvider[] filterProviders, ActionContext actionContext, List`1 filterItems)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.FilterFactory.GetAllFilters(IFilterProvider[] filterProviders, ActionContext actionContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvokerCache.GetCachedResult(ControllerContext controllerContext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ControllerRequestDelegateFactory.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.b__0(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Program.cs (condensed)
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)

builder.Services.AddControllers()
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
    options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
    options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
}

// ... other service registrations

var app = builder.Build();

var antiforgery = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IAntiforgery>();

app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    var requestPath = context.Request.Path.Value;

    if (string.Equals(requestPath, "/login", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context); 
        context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
    }
});

// ... additional app usings

app.Run();

Based on this answer - I added the following option when adding controllers to the services but I'm still getting the same error.
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute());
});

What am I missing here? I've reread Microsoft's documentation and I believe I have everything setup like they show, but obviously I'm missing something here.

Sometimes it just takes posting to Stack Overflow to solve my own problems.
After rereading the documentation again, I noticed this snippet.

Calling AddControllers does not enable antiforgery tokens. AddControllersWithViews must be called to have built-in antiforgery token support.

Changing AddControllers to AddControllersWithViews fixed this issue.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

